# Add Website to the Internet Explorer Trusted Site in Win32

Tags: c++, internet-explorer

I am writing an application which adds configured url to the trusted site settings in Internet explorer. I am writing an Win32 application, so i can't use interop services. Can anyone please help to sort this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,
Rajesh

Comment: Wouldn't the conventional solution be to *ask the user* if he trusts the site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [Internet Security Manager Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537026%28VS.85%29.aspx) over COM.

Comment: Correct, specifically the SetZoneMapping API. Note, however, that doing this could be considered malicious behavior (and result in blocking by AV tools) unless the user is provided informed consent about what you're doing.